# itertools product to generate all possible strings of size 3

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, cartesian-product

Input:

```
pos_1= 'AVNMHDRW' 
pos_2= 'KNTHDYBW'
pos_3= 'KVNGSDRB'
```

Trying to find all possible triplets using one item from pos_1, one from pos_2, and one from pos_3

I'm trying to figure out how to use itertools.product(*) but I'm a little confused

Ultimately, I want to create a list (or generator object) of all the different possibilities by taking one from pos_1 then one from pos_2 and then one from pos_3

Example output:

```
'AKK','ANV','WWB'
```

pos_1 stands for position one and so on for pos_2 and pos_3.

Comment: Not sure why product you need, but you can make generator simply as `g = ( [v1,v2,v3] for v1 in pos_1 for v2 in pos_2 for v3 in pos_3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
itertools.product(pos_1, pos_2, pos_3)
```

This can be iterated over; if you want a list, just pass it to `list`.

What exactly is the issue?

Edit: This produces tuples of the items from each source. If you want to join them back into strings, you can do that manually when you iterate:

```
for a, b, c in itertools.product(pos_1, pos_2, pos_3):
    do_something_with(a + b + c)
```

or to create the list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[a + b + c for a, b, c in itertools.product(pos_1, pos_2, pos_3)]
```

Comment: Or for fun, `map(''.join, itertools.product(pos_1, pos_2, pos_3))`

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: [In python is ther a concise way to a list comprehension with multiple iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329886/in-python-is-there-a-concise-way-to-use-a-list-comprehension-with-multiple-iter).

In your case:

```
triples = [ a+b+c for a in pos_1 for b in pos_2 for c in pos_3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make such generator using generator expression:

```
g = (v1+v2+v3  for v1 in pos_1 for v2 in pos_2 for v3 in pos_3)
```