# concatenate each characters from 2 strings in a list

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to concatenate each character from 2 strings in a list. Also, is it possible to do it by using list comprehension?

```
s = ['ab', 'cde']
```

Result:

```
['ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'bc', 'bd', 'be']
```

Comment: Related: [itertools product to generate all possible strings of size 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27413493/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate, but for completeness, here's your answer:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = ['ab', 'cde']
>>> [''.join(t) for t in itertools.product(*s)]
['ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'bc', 'bd', 'be']
```

Answer (score 4):

This will do it

```
result = [i + j for i in s[0] for j in s[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
s = ['ab', 'cde']
result = [''.join(item) for item in itertools.product(*s)]
print(result)  # ['ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'bc', 'bd', 'be']
```

There is no need to reimplement the wheel with list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
s = ['ab', 'cde']

word1 = list(s[0])
word2 = list(s[1])

s2 = []

for c1 in word1:
  for c2 in word2:
      s2.append(c1+c2)

print(s2)
```

Comment: This is a more verbose version of [Mark Bailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858533/4518341)